# Why is AutoGeneratingColumn filling every dropdown list with that of final column?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am trying to make an auto-generated GridView that will put an editable ComboBox in each cell in each column that contains strings. The selectable items for each column should match the values that are already in that column in the DataTable. The code below almost achieves this, but for some reason, it fills the drop-down list for every column with the drop-down list for the final column.

```
    private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, 
        DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) {
        if (e.PropertyType == typeof(string)) {
            DataGridTemplateColumn comboColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            comboColumn.Header = e.PropertyName;
            comboColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["ComboBoxDataTemplate"];
            FrameworkElementFactory comboBoxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
            List<string> list = (DataContext as MainVM).PartClassVM.DataTable.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(row => row[e.PropertyName].ToString()).Distinct().ToList<string>();
            comboBoxFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, list); 
            comboColumn.CellTemplate.VisualTree = comboBoxFactory;
            e.Column = comboColumn;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how to get around it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It happens as `ColumnType` is set to type of `String` by default.

But when you are populating your `DataTable`, you can set type for your column explicitly:

```
YourDataTable.Columns.Add("Column 1", typeof(bool));
YourDataTable.Columns.Add("Column 2", typeof(string));
YourDataTable.Columns.Add("Column 3", typeof(int));
YourDataTable.Columns.Add("Column 4", typeof(double));
```

and  based on type you can use your necessary `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
if (e.PropertyType == typeof(string)) {
   ...
}
else if(e.PropertyType == typeof(bool)) {
   ...
}
else if(e.PropertyType == typeof(int)) {
...
}
```

You can see what types `DataTable` supports in [the MSDN article.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want `DataTable` to support your own, some custom types(for example, Person, Department, Car). then you should create your custom `DataTable` which inherits from `DataTable`.

**Update:**

I am not sure, but, in my view, `AutoGeneratingColumn` event has a goal to customize a column(not a cell) - using `DataTemplate`, but not populating `DataGrid`.

So your goal is to populate `DataGridComboBoxColumn` from `DataTable` using MVVM approach.

Comment: I still don't understand why the ItemsSource for the ComboBox in column A,B,C and D seems to bind to the list of selectable options for column E. You say it is because the ColumnType is set to type string? That does not really explain it for me. Could you expand on that please?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then now you have `ComboBox'es` in all `DataGridColumns`? But you want to show `ComboBox`in `DataGridColumn` only if type of `DataGridColumn` is `string`? If yes, then it happens cause all `DataGridColumn's`  are `string` types. Please, clarify if I misunderstood you.

Comment: I do have ComboBoxes in all DataGridColumns, and that is what I want. But the selectable options that every ComboBox Column provides, is currently {"LH1","LH2","RH1","RH2"}. This is correct for the final column, but not for the other columns. The other columns should have different lists of strings in them.

Comment: @christiaantober cause you are selecting some data from `DataTable`. Are you sure `e.PropertyName` in `row[e.PropertyName]` is a number. Cause you get data from array by index. Debug this piece of code. Here you are populating data.

Comment: e.PropertyName is a string, but this works because DataRow row will accept strings as a key to a specific column (a bit like a dictionary).

Comment: @christiaantober so every time when 'AutoGeneratingColumn' is called the code returns various rows from DataTable? Have you debugged what data comes to you?

Comment: Yes it does. I have put a breakpoint in this method to check that the correct list is being retrieved in each call, and it is. But still when the final DataGrid is generated, the selectable options in each column end up all the same.